# Probability - checking probability with constant

Tags: probability

I'm not sure the following is right.

If $P(X=n) = a(1/3)^n, n = 1,2,3\dots$
$a$ is a constant. 
I need to find $P(X>3)$

So I just do $1-P(X<3) \rightarrow a(1/3)^1+ a(1/3)^2+a(1/3)^3?$

Also, I have trouble solving for C. I thought to do it's by recursion. to assume $P(0) = a$. then maybe to do some general equation?

Comment: $P(X>3) = 1 - (P(X=0)+P(X=1)+P(X=2)+P(X=3))$

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  In order for MathJax commands to be effective, they must be surrounded with`$` signs.

Comment: You have the right idea, but you need to solve for $a$ also.

Comment: Quite a long way from the right idea since $1-P(X \le 3)$ is required, which is a sum not a product, and the $P(X=0) $ term is missing.

Answer (score 1):

$$\mathbb{P}(X > 3) = \sum\limits_{i=4}^{+\infty} \mathbb{P}(X=i) = \sum\limits_{i=4}^{+\infty} a(\frac{1}{3})^{i} = a\frac{1}{3^{4}}\sum\limits_{j=0}^{+\infty} (\frac{1}{3})^{j} = a \cdot \frac{1}{3^{4}} \cdot \frac{1}{1-(\frac{1}{3})} = \frac{a}{2\cdot 3^{3}}$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have a question thought, shouldn't I first solve a somehow? to get to an answer without constants.

Comment: You can find the constant $a$ in order to prove that the function you defined, actually defines a density, which translates into $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{+\infty} p_{X}(i) = 1$, which give $a\cdot \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{3}} = 1$ so $a = \frac{2}{3}$